# Problem rendering nextjs page inside puppeteer inside a docker container

Tags: docker, puppeteer, next.js

I come before you as a last hope. I have a project where I need to be able to export a page to a pdf file.
The project is a nextjs site deployed in a docker swarm.

Considering the SSR/CSR of nextjs, I've elected to use puppeteer to render & export the page.
To do that, I've created a POST endpoint taking the url & the token as parameters to allow the rendering of the page server side.

The export code :

```
let cfg = {
    headless: true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-web-security"]
};

if (serverRuntimeConfig.chromiumPath != undefined) {
    cfg.executablePath = serverRuntimeConfig.chromiumPath
}

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(cfg);
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', msg => {
    for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
        console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
});

await page.setCookie(...cookies)
await page.goto(query);
await page.waitFor(10000)
const pdf = await page.pdf({
    format: "A4",
    scale: 0.75,
    printBackground: true
});
await browser.close();
return pdf;
```

As you can see, my page requires authentification, so I set the cookie using puppeteer.

When I use this locally, absolutely no problem. My page is correctly loaded and exported.
Problems come when deployed using docker.
I've console.loged the problem, I load some data async in the componentDidMount hook and the loading just stops when I launch my first request to fetch the data. No error, nothing. It just stops.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("yeah");
    let ad = await apiCase.doRequest(...);
    console.log("re yeah");
}
```

Got a "yeah", no "re yeah".

Dockerfile (the prod part of it)

```
FROM alpine:edge as prod

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=prune-builder /src /app

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    chromium \
    nss \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    harfbuzz \
    ca-certificates \
    ttf-freefont \
    nodejs \
    npm

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

Any ideas ? I'd put my money on some stupid configuration problem in the container, but It seems I can't find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, if anyone have this problem well... There is no problem.

I tried to mount my image locally, works perfectly. Problem seems to be about network access one the container is deployed on the swarm.